# How to enable Aptana features for Java project in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana

How to enable Aptana 3 features like code assist, debugger etc for Java project in eclipse?
I want to add these features to existing project (not creating new one).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to 'hack your way in'. I did not try this one, but it might just work, since the Studio looks for the project 'Natures' to determine how to operate.

Create an Aptana Studio Web Project and then go to the created folder on your disk and look for the .project file. Open the file and look for the 'natures' and the 'builders' element.
Copy those into the .project file of your Java project and start the Studio.

Once the project has the Aptana Natures, you might be able to add/remove Natures using the project's 'Properties' dialog ('Project Natures' item).

Hope that helps ;)